# Why does JavaScriptSerializer.Deserealize produce empty result?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json-deserialization, webmethod

I am trying to get the results of an API to return only selected attributes as a JSON string or object. The full return `JSON` string looks like this:

```
{"ListEvents":[{"EventID":1,"EventName":"Debby 
2000","State":"PR","EventType":"Tropical or 
Extratropical","Days":5,"LSTStart":"\/Date(966643200000- 
0000)\/","LSTEnd":"\/Date(967075200000-0000)\/"},{"EventID":2,...]}
```

To do this, it seems I need to employ a `Serializer` and create some public classes to act as a template outside of my `WebMethod` function.

```
public class RII_Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string _appRootDir = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/");
    public class Flood_Dataset
    {
       public int EventID { get; set; }
        public string EventName { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string EventType { get; set; }
    }
     public class ListEvent
    {
        public List<Flood_Dataset> ListEvents { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    { 
        public ListEvent Data_Response { get; set; }
    }
   ...
```

I then try to apply these public classes with my serialization after making my `WebRequest` and getting my `HttpWebResponse`:

```
public RootObject GetFloodData()
{
  WebRequest requestObj = WebRequest.Create(url);
  requestObj.Method = "GET";
  requestObj.ContentType = "application/json";
  requestObj.Timeout = 10 * 1000;
  HttpWebResponse responseObj = null;
  RootObject jsonResponse = null;
  JavaScriptSerializer returnJson = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  try
  {
     string strresult = null;
      responseObj = (HttpWebResponse)requestObj.GetResponse();
      using (Stream stream = responseObj.GetResponseStream())
      {
           StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
           strresult = sr.ReadToEnd();
           sr.Close();
      }

      jsonResponse = returnJson.Deserialize<RootObject>(strresult);
      return jsonResponse;
        ....
   }
}
```

When I check my variable `strresult` in the debugger, I see `"{\"EventID\":71,\"EventName\":\"Maria 2017\",...}"`. but when it gets to the 
line `jsonResponse = returnJson.Deserialize<RootObject>(strresult);`, I only see `Data_Response` as null next to `{recurrence_interval_app.RII_Service.RootObject}`. What am I doing wrong here? I am modeling my solution after this similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539731/deserialize-json-web-api-response-nested-objects).

Comment: Because the input data you are trying to deserialize matches `ListEvent` rather than `RootObject`. Your input will need the property `{"Data_Response" : { "ListEvents" : [ ... ] } }`